# Why three times "Tenacious"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I found "Tenacious" listed three times at https://stackoverflow.com/badges.

I can't find the reason - Why three time listing of single badge?

See attached image. Snap Shot time 24-JUL-2010 - 11:40:AM Indian Time

[alt text http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/1429/screenshot20100724at113.png](http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/1429/screenshot20100724at113.png)

Comment: Once, twice, three times tenacious ... we will sort it

Comment: Confirmed. The three Tenacious have tag ID 225, 232 and 233 respectively.

Comment: "The ironing is delicious."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My bug, it's fixed now (vote me up so community does not bump me)

Comment: "So community does not bump me"... I had a vision of a huge being made of bouncy balls floating through SO's offices and bumping the developers occasionally, causing broken arms and legs in the process.

Comment: @Pekka quite often Jeff will unleash the prisoner style ball that chases us cross continent to punish us for bugs that should not have happened http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=op7IgFbT8l0

Comment: and the only thing that can save you from it is upvotes. I see, and will vote accordingly in the future. That also puts the comprehensive health plan into perspective that Joel always brags about.